# Unix Truncate Column in csv file

Tags: text-processing

How do I truncate column "test10" to 5 characters from Unix command line?

From this

```
test1,test2,test3,test4,test10,test11,test12,test17
rh,mbn,ccc,khj,ee3 eeeeeEeee ee$eeee e.eeeee2eeeee5eeeeeeee,a2,3,u
hyt,bb,mb,khj,R ee3ee eeEeee ee$eeee e.eeeee2eeeee5eeeeeeee,a,5,r
mbn,htr,ccc,fdf,F1ee eeeeEeee ee$eeee e.eeeee2eeeee5eeeeeeee,a,e,r
```

To this

```
test1,test2,test3,test4,test10,test11,test12,test17
rh,mbn,ccc,khj,ee3 e,a2,3,u
hyt,bb,mb,khj,R ee3,a,5,r
mbn,htr,ccc,fdf,F1ee ,a,e,r
```

Comment: Are you actually running Unix or is it Linux? Do you have access to GNU tools?

Comment: I am using Solaris 10 command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your file really is as simple as your example, you can do one of:

- `awk`

  ```
  $ awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR>1{$5=substr($5,1,5)}1' file 
  test1,test2,test3,test4,test10,test11,test12,test17
  rh,mbn,ccc,khj,ee3 e,a2,3,u
  hyt,bb,mb,khj,R ee3,a,5,r
  mbn,htr,ccc,fdf,F1ee ,a,e,r
  ```

  #### Explanation

  The `-F,` sets the input field separator to `,` and the `-vOFS=,` sets the variable `OFS` (the output field separator) to `,`. `NR` is the current line number, so the script above will change the 5th field to a 5-character substring of itself. The lone `1` is awk shorthand for "print this line".
- `perl`

  ```
  $ perl -F, -lane '$F[4]=~s/(.{5}).*/$1/ if $.>1; print join ",", @F' file 
  test1,test2,test3,test4,test10,test11,test12,test17
  rh,mbn,ccc,khj,ee3 e,a2,3,u
  hyt,bb,mb,khj,R ee3,a,5,r
  mbn,htr,ccc,fdf,F1ee ,a,e,r
  ```

  #### Explanation

  The `-a` makes perl act like awk and split its input lines on the character given by `-F` and saves them as elements of the array `@F`. We then remove all but the 1st 5 characters of the 5th field (they start counting at `0`) and then print the resulting `@F` array joined with commas.
- `sed`

  ```
  $ sed  -E '1!s/(([^,]+,){4}[^,]{5,5})[^,]*,/\1,/' file
  test1,test2,test3,test4,test10,test11,test12,test17
  rh,mbn,ccc,khj,ee3 e,a2,3,u
  hyt,bb,mb,khj,R ee3,a,5,r
  mbn,htr,ccc,fdf,F1ee ,a,e,r
  ```

  #### Explanation

  This is the substitution operator whose general format is `s/original.replacement/`. The `1!` means "don't do this for the 1st line". The regular expression matches a set of non-`,` followed by a `,` 4 times (`([^,]+,){4}`), then any 5 non-`,` characters (`[^,]{5}`)—these are the 1st 5 of the 5th field—and then anything else until the end of the field (`[^,]+,`). All this is replaced with the first part of the line, effectively truncating the field.

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```bash
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR > 1 { $5 = substr($5,1,5) }; 1' data.csv
```

The `-F` flag sets the input field separator, and the `BEGIN` block sets the output field separator to whatever the input field separator is (a comma).

If the ordinal number of the current record (`NR`) is greater than one (i.e. we've passed the header line), then the `substr()` function will truncate the fifth field (column) to at most five characters. This avoids modifying the first line of the input data.

The lone `1` will cause `awk` to print the (possibly) modified record (line) to standard output.